# I want to make my nuke command only for those role which have ManageMessages permission.How do i do this?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, discord, discord.js

> Main.js nuke commands

```
if (command === 'nuke'){
        client.commands.get('nuke').execute(message, args);
```

> nuke.js file in commands folder

```
module.exports = {
name: 'nuke',
description: "the bot will reply nuke gif!",
execute(message, args){
    
        if(message.member.roles.cache.has('755968860817195029'))
    {
    message.channel.bulkDelete("100").then(message.channel.send("NEWS HEADLINES:- **A BOMB JUST DROPPED HERE WHICH DELETED ALL THE MESSAGES (R.I.P.)**"));
    (message.channel.send("https://tenor.com/view/kozhi-nuclear-bomb-gif-18586883"));
}
```

`else { message.channel.send("It seems you dont have required permissions to do this commands!") } } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than checking for a role, you could check if the member user has the given permission. Discord.js has a utility for this on member objects, [hasPermission](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission). You can use this to check if the member has the "MANAGE_MESSAGES" permission.